# Uniqueness of convex combinations in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Assume that we have a vector space $V$, which is endowed with an inner product. Suppose that points $x,y,z \in V$ satisfy that $\vert\vert x-z\vert\vert=(1-\lambda)\vert\vert x-y\vert\vert$ and  $\vert\vert y-z\vert\vert=\lambda\vert\vert x-y\vert\vert$, for some $\lambda \in (0,1)$.

Under these conditions, does it have to hold that $z=\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y$?

Comment: Yep! This implies $\|x - y\| = \|x - z\| + \|z - y\|$, which gives us equality in the triangle inequality, and hence equality in Cauchy-Schwarz. From this, we can conclude that $x - z$ and $z - y$ are non-negative multiples of each other. You can then use the original equations to deduce the conclusion.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you